# Reducing switch-statement in Ctrl to disabled input field (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Generally the code statement works but I guess it isn't a good practice because the variables are repeated in each case of the switch statement. So I don't know how to reduce the code or is there an alternative to switch?

At first the code in the Ctrl:

```
$scope.searchDisabled = function (num) {
                switch (num) {
                    case 1:
                        $scope.disLname = false;
                        $scope.disFname = true;
                        $scope.disGroup = true;
                        $scope.group = {};
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $scope.disLname = true;
                        $scope.disFname = false;
                        $scope.disGroup = true;
                        $scope.group = {};
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $scope.disLname = true;
                        $scope.disFname = true;
                        $scope.disGroup = false;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $scope.disLname = true;
                        $scope.disFname = true;
                        $scope.disGroup = true;
                        $scope.group = {};
                        break;
                    default:
                        $log.error('ERR! variable isn\'t a num:', num);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

And at last my view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="searchForm">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Lastname:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search lastname" name="Lname" ng-model="search.lname" ng-click="searchDisabled(1)" ng-disabled="disLname" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="searchDisabled(1)" ng-model="formRadio.checked" value="1" ng-hide="!disLname" />
                    </div><!--end radio btn -->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Firstname:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search firstname" name="Fname" ng-model="search.fname" ng-click="searchDisabled(2)" ng-disabled="disFname" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="searchDisabled(2)" ng-model="formRadio.checked" value="2" ng-hide="!disFname"  />
                    </div><!--end radio btn -->
                </div>   
               <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Group:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <ui-select ng-model="group.selected" theme="selectize" ng-click="searchDisabled(3)" ng-disabled="disGroup">
                        <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose a group">
                            {{$select.selected.name}}
                        </ui-select-match>
                        <ui-select-choices repeat="group in groups | filter: $select.search">
                            <span ng-bind-html="group.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                            <small ng-bind-html="group.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
                        </ui-select-choices>
                    </ui-select>
                </div><!--end select group -->
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="searchDisabled(3)" ng-model="formRadio.checked" value="3" ng-hide="!disGroup" />
                </div><!--end radio btn -->
            </div>
```

For the Group field I'm using ui-select module of angularjs. However my question is how can I reduce or replace the switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are pretty simple:

- disLname is true unless value is 1
- disFname is true unless value is 2
- disGroup is true unless value is 3
- group is {} unless value is 3

I've also added checks for num is not a number, and num out of bounds.

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/ax6crvsm/) - look at the console of the bottom left pane.

```
scope.searchDisabled = function (num) {
    var value = parseInt(num, 10);

    if(isNaN(num)) {
        $log.error('ERR! variable isn\'t a num:', num);
        return;
    }

    if(num < 1 || num > 4) {
        $log.error('ERR! variable is out of range:', num);
        return;
    }

    $scope.disLname = value !== 1;
    $scope.disFname = value !== 2;
    $scope.disGroup = value !== 3;
    $scope.group = value === 3 ? undefined : {};
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the group have an failure. When I select a group then the list won't filtered the data with the chosen group.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do following

```
  $scope.searchDisabled = function (num) {
                        $scope.disLname = true;
                        $scope.disFname = true;
                        $scope.disGroup = true;
                        $scope.group = {};

                switch (num) {
                    case 1:
                        $scope.disLname = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $scope.disFname = false;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $scope.disGroup = false;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    default:
                        $log.error('ERR! variable isn\'t a num:', num);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but your solution have the same problem like the answer above.. As soon as I select a group there doesn't give the filtered data.